# SQL Insert Syntax error

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax

I wrote the following code in a Java program.

```
public int insertRecord()
       {

connection=PersistentieController.getInstance().getConnection();

int resultaat = 0;

String sql ="INSERT INTO TestDb (Nr Dossier, Année) VALUES (?,?)";

          try 
          {
             pstatement = initStatement(connection, sql);
             pstatement.setString(1, "9999");            
             pstatement.setInt(2, 2012);

             resultaat = pstatement.executeUpdate(); 
             pstatement.close();

          } //einde try
          catch ( SQLException sqlException ){
              sqlException.printStackTrace();

          }  

          return resultaat;

       } //einde insert()
```

I recieve an syntax error.
I checked that i don't use reserved words.
Any ideas?
Thx.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Also you have a table called `TestDb`?

Comment: I use an Acces Db. When I change the column name to NrDossier the error is gone which is great and i get 1 as a result which means it worked but when i check my db it didn't add the the new record :s. My table has that name cause i created a test table before using the actual table.

Comment: Try it with square brackets around the field name, ie [Nr Dossier]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have escape the columnnames (*with space such as `Nr Dossier`*) .

backtick if you are using **MySQL**,

```
INSERT INTO TestDb (`Nr Dossier`, `Année`) VALUES (?,?)
```

brackets if you are using **SQLServer** and **MS Access**,

```
INSERT INTO TestDb ([Nr Dossier], [Année]) VALUES (?,?)
```

Comment: Hi john
Using [] the error is gone and i get a successful result but it still doesn't show in the table. Could it be a primary key issue? Its an autonumber field so I don't think so.

Comment: which field is `auto_incremented`?

Comment: I have 3 field
Key -> autoincrement
NrDossier -> Text
Année -> Number
I don't get any error anymore but the new value isn't inserted to my table whilst it is successfully executed.

Comment: then the `auto-incremented` colum should not be included in your query. Is should only be this: `INSERT INTO TestDb ([Année]) VALUES (?)`

Comment: It isn't in my query. The autoincrement is the field key, which i left out.

Comment: what other is generated? I don't see any error in your query.

Comment: With your help the query works like a charm but even though it has inserted the new record to the table, its doesn't show. Don't understand why not.

Answer (score 0):

In this  line of code  String sql ="INSERT INTO TestDb (Nr Dossier, Année) VALUES (?,?)"; you have mentioned column name `Nr Dossier` which is invalid column name.

Comment: I use an Acces Db. When I change the column name to NrDossier the error is gone which is great and i get 1 as a result which means it worked but when i check my db it didn't add the the new record :s. Any suggestions? Thx

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest its because your field 'Nr Dossier' has a space in it.

You didnt mention which SQL type you're using, however [] or ` marks can often fix this.

Comment: I use an Acces Db. When I change the column name to NrDossier the error is gone which is great and i get 1 as a result which means it worked but when i check my db it didn't add the the new record :s.
Any suggestions?
Thx

Comment: Im not so hot on java, so, my guesses would be, did it use a different copy of the database? is 1 supposed to be the returned effected rows or actually its "Error 1".. in which case it could be index related, or, couldnt convert field types or such

Comment: When i get 1 as a result it should mean that the execution was successful though the record isn't there. The connection should be fine cause i can read every single record in my table.

Comment: Then it suggests the file you checked wasnt the one it used.

Comment: The return value 1 is actually the amount of rows infected by the operation. Here it is 1 cause I insert 1 row.
Wouldn't know what other table could be used. If the tablename would be wrong i'm supposed to get an error.

Comment: Well it clearly put it somewhere! How are you checking it worked?

Comment: By checking my table :s. How could i check another way?

Comment: Well, as Ive suggested a couple of times, are you sure you are looking at the same file it did

Comment: Can't think of a way to trace it. How could it be looking at a different file? When I make it read first it shows me the right values but when I want to insert, the new record isn't shown in the table.

Comment: You've already marked you had an answer - continuing this conversation seems mute.. AS my answer wasnt it

Comment: Both answers were it for my question about my query but couldn't click them both. 
Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: I have an answer to my syntax error. But for some reason my Insert isn't shown in my table, that's why i'm still asking. I could start a new question but thought i could get it here.

Answer (score 0):

use the string values inside single quote's :

```
String sql ="INSERT INTO TestDb ('Nr Dossier', 'Année') VALUES (?,?)";
```